# In Terminal, what's the difference between "cd /" and "cd ~"?

Tags: command-line, terminal, dash-shell, tilde

I don't understand the difference between these two. They both seem to take me to the root directory. Are there differences?

Answer (score 2):

cd ~ takes you to the home directory

cd / takes you to the root directory

these will be the same if you are running it as root

Comment: So, what's the difference between root and home? I'm assuming sometimes they can be the same. When are they different? Can you provide an example? Thank you!

Comment: Normally, if you are logged in as a regular user, your home directory will be something like /home/user
Technically your home directory is whatever is defined in the HOME variable

use the command "echo $HOME" to see what your home directory is

Answer (score 0):

"cd ~" usually takes you to the home directory of the logged user.